# Is it possible to write "isa"/"match" function

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to write "isa" or "match" function on Haskell without TH? It must get constructor and values and to match value with this constructor, but constructor can have multiple arguments. Example:

```
data X = X a b|Y {age::Int, name::String}
isa c v = ???
goal_of_exercise x y|iff all (isa X) x y = 1
                    |iff any (isa Y) x y = 2
  where iff agg c a b = agg c [a, b]
```

Or may be exists another solution of goal-of-exercise... ?

Comment: What would the signature of `isa` be again? What's the signature of `goal_of_exercise` (specifically, what's `x` and `y`) Where's the `a` and `b` in the `X` constructor coming from - did you want a parametric or a higher-rank type?

Comment: Bartek, I don't know, so I'm asking :) IMHO it's not possible without TH. But OK, may be another way to implement `goal_of_exercise` in simple way? A lot of permutations... What to do...

Comment: You haven't answered any of my questions, and I can't answer yours without at least some explanation. What, *specifically*, is `goal_of_exercise` again?

Comment: Better is to have generic "isa", which will work with any kind of types.

Comment: And what would that function do? What would it take, and what would it return? You're failing to describe your goal, so as a consequence your problem statement is entirely unclear.

Comment: as I said already, it can not get type like in dynamic languages, so it will take constructor which is 1st citizen. And it must return, sure, Bool. Imagine `isa X the_x == True` like in many other languages, like C# similar construct, may be F#.

Comment: Pattern matching happens in runtime, right? So there is type tag, in the box, right? So, there is such "system" function, and Haskell uses them.

Comment: Yes, and it's called pattern matching. You can just match for the constructor.

Comment: I think based on the question, the OP wants something similar as the `..=/2` predicate in Prolog.

Comment: "Pattern-matching" is syntax construct only. But in runtime something is called. And this is function which gets type tag from boxed value IMHO.

Comment: OK, if it is not possible, how to implement functions based on pattern matching of its args when there are a lot of permutations? Should be a way...

Comment: I don't see a load of permutations in your example. You have two constructors and you can just match for both, like in my 1st example.

Comment: ah, this is the snippet only. Actually I have sum of types, something like `data D = A ...|B ...|C ...|D ...|E|G` and try to write `Monoid` of it.

Comment: Well, if every constructor can hold different data, then you obviously need different matches. If they share the same data, consider splitting it into `data  DType = A | B | C ... | G` and `data DValues = Values ...`, and combining them into `data D = D Type Values`. That way you can have just one match. This whole question is an X/Y problem.

Comment: Bartek, I'm newbie, so ask it, but I see that there is a `pat` construct in Haskell, also there is proposal for Active Patterns, also there is `ViewPatterns`, so may be there is some intelligent solution...

Comment: And if what you *actually* had was "a sum of types, something like data D = A ...|B ...|C ...|D ...|E|G" and all you wanted was " to write Monoid of it", **you should have asked that question**.

Comment: Answer on both my questions will solve the problem. One either second. Better is to have answer on generic problem... OK, I found this - https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/thih/thih.pdf. It looks close but complex

Answer (score 3):

The function you're asking for is not just impossible to write - it's absolutely nonsensical in the context of Haskell.

In Haskell all (most of) your data types are indeed, as you've observed, tagged unions carrying type information in runtime. This allows pattern matching to work:

```
data D = A | B

whichD :: D -> String
whichD A = "it's an A"
whichD B = "it's a B"
```

This works for constructors of *one particular type*, though. The signature of `whichD` specifically says it takes a `D`, which can be constructed using one of its constructors. If you wanted to extend it to, say, take an analogous `D'`, you could use a sum type for that:

```
data OneOf = OneD D | OneD' D'
```

---

Now, there are cases where this is not the case, namely parametrized contexts:

```
specialShow :: Show a => a -> String
specialShow a = "it's a special " ++ show a
```

So now, is it possible to change the behavior of `specialShow` for some particular `a`s? Yes in principle, but not under that signature. Typically you'd introduce your own type class and provide specific instances for the types you want, and use generic code for all other types you want to bring in. This can pose some problems with overlapping instances, but that's solvable.

---

What if you *insisted* on doing the runtime check? I don't think that would even work in all cases, but possibly using some compiler intrinsics you'd be able to force it to tell you more about the actual value. I am pretty sure there's no standard Haskell way to do that, as it's essentially breaking the type system abstraction.

Comment: (1) "In Haskell every type is ... a tagged union" -- false.  There are also function types and various non-algebraic built-in types.  (2) "is it possible to change the behavior of `specialShow` for some particular `a`s?  Sure"  -- false (unless you have some other signature in mind, or by "possible" you didn't mean "possible within the language")

Comment: @luqui 1) good point - I'll edit to reflect. 2) I meant "possible, but not like you want it too", i.e. requires using the whole shebang I talk about later. Not sure I that needs clarification.